# Is there an iPad PDF Reader app that has autoscroll?

Tags: ipad, software-recommendation, pdf

I read stacks of PDFs on my iPad and I have downloaded (and paid for) a few PDF readers hoping to find an auto-scroll feature, without luck.

Does anyone know of any iPad app that can auto-scroll PDF's (preferably with Dropbox integration so I can get at my PDFs easily!).

Thanks

Comment: Recommend the feature to developers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To date, I have found only one PDF reader that has Dropbox connectivity and has autoscroll(after a fashion.)

It is PDF Reader Pro [iTunes Link.](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/pdf-reader-pro/id300298606) It is a universal app that works on both iPad and iPhone and ties to Box.net, Dropbox, Googledocs, and iDisk.  It has an "Autoflow" feature that allows timed jumps (from 5 to 100 seconds) of a preset number of pixels (20 to 400.)  I bought it at the low price of $0.99 and it performs, pretty much, as expected.  It has some basic annotation capabilities and "scans" documents using the camera in the iPad 2.  I have an original so I couldn't test that feature.

I haven't used it a lot as I like the annotative capabilities of iAnnotate, but the app is a good fall back if I need the autoflow feature.

For $0.99 it looks to be a solid reader that fits the requirements you laid out.

Comment: Great thanks Andy. Sounds like what I need, I will check it out.

Answer (score 1):

I think [GoodReader](http://goodreader.net/goodreader.html) ([iTunes Link](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/goodreader-for-ipad/id363448914?mt=8)) is right up your alley.

It supports PDFs primarily, but according to it's site also supports Microsoft Office, Apple iWork, HTML WebArchive, images/audio/video files.

It can connect to Dropbox shares, download resources directly off the web (and some other protocols, FTP, SFTP, WebDAV) in-app, supports Document Sharing (file loading via iTunes), features autoscroll, and many many more features and customizations that you didn't ask about!

It is unfortunately NOT a Universal app, USD$5 for the iPad version. And another USD$5 should you ever want to buy it for an iPhone/iPod.

Comment: Tried GoodReader, unfortunately it only autoscrolls for .txt files and not PDFs :-(

Comment: Did you down vote me for that? :(

Comment: Nope I didn't...

Comment: I did read a workaround regarding PDFs and GoodReader. I believe it was something about using the "PDF Reflow" feature, which turns it into text, which can be autoscrolled. Worthless if you're reading a PDF with significant style or photos, but worth a try otherwise!

Comment: Tried that aswell - as far as I can see it only seems to scroll to the end of the current page and doesn't continue to the next page...unless I am doing something wrong.

Comment: I'm afraid I can't really provide any more insight. Sorry. I don't use GoodReader for this aspect.

Answer (score 1):

If good reader has PDF autoscroll I haven't found it.
What it CAN do is extract text from a PDF, display it
as if it were plain text, and autoscroll that.

Answer (score -3):

Try Filemagnet!  You can control autoscroll with the tilt of your device.